# How can I reference the selected device's serial number in an Android Studio build configuration?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to make an Android studio build configuration which runs a gradle task with an adb command. Currently the task fails if there are multiple android devices enumerating in adb because the task has no way to specify which device to run the adb command on.

I know I can specify a device in adb by passing the serial number to `adb -s <serial>`, but I don't know how I can get the serial number of the device selected in android studio's run configuration drop down:

[image: Android Studio configuration example]

So for example, in this scenario I would want `Galaxy Nexus API 29`'s serial number to get passed to my gradle task so I can pass it to `adb -s`. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: You can use `adb -d shell` (for the connected physical device) or `adb -e shell` (for emulators) in case you don't know the serial number. For more information i recommend you to check the Android documentation for ADB: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#commandsummary

Comment: @AstritVeliu thanks but this doesn't associate my adb command with the selected device in AS. Ideally I'd like a way to not have to modify the gradle script code when I switch devices.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `adb devices`. It returns device's serials. You can also use `-l` parameter (`adb devices -l`) to display serial and deviceModel

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my question well. I want to automate this in a gradle task that gets run in a run configuration. I need a way for that gradle task to know which adb device is selected in the android studio dropdown. Calling adb devices wont tell my gradle task which adb device to select from that output.

Comment: Oh ok. I did a short research on whether avdmanager can be used for this, but I found nothing. Sorry